# A newcommand for more than one formula

Tags: macros

I have some formula such as `z_{(h_{1},h_{2},h_{3})}` and `z_{(h_{4},h_{5},h_{6})}`. How can one introduce a `\newcommand{}{}` for all of such formulas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please confirm that the only things that differ between the two formulas are the level-two subscripts -- 1/2/3 vs. 4/5/6. Please also confirm that there are always exactly 3 items in the subscript position to the right of `z`.

Comment: @Mico: Very optimistic ;-)

Comment: @Mico The difference is only in indices and they have always 3 items in subscript.

Comment: @FahimB: What about `\zz{1}` that produces `z_{(h_{1},h_{2},h_{3})}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They forgot `xinttools`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xinttools}

% Thank you very much. I will be very thankful if you write the commands for
% z_{j_{1}(h_{1},h_{2})} and z_{k(h_{3},h_{4},h_{5})}

\newcommand{\zz}[2]{z_{#1(\xintFor ##1 in {#2}\do {h_{##1}\xintifForLast{}{,}})}}
\begin{document}

\[ \zz{j_{1}}{1,2} = \zz{k}{3, 4, 5}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

```
  \newcommand\zz[3]{z_{(h_{#1},h_{#2},h_{#3})}
```

then  you can use  and `\zz{1}{2}{3}` and `\zz{4}{5}{6}` or even `\zz123` and `\zz456`

Comment: +1. I was going to call the macro `\zzz`, to be mildly mnemonic of the fact that it takes 3 arguments...

Comment: @Mico and there was I being fearful of Ulrike chiding me for using too many z and you comment I have too few. I can't win.

Answer (score 17):

It's not difficult to extend it to any number of subscripts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zz}{m}
 {
  z
  \sp{}\sb
   {
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_fahim_z_subscripts_seq { h\sb{##1} }
     }
    (\seq_use:Nn \l_fahim_z_subscripts_seq { , })
   }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_fahim_z_subscripts_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\zz{1,2,3}+\zz{4,5,6}=\zz{1,2,3,4,5,6}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This can be generalized to different base letters and different processing of the subscripts. The trailing optional argument sets how to treat each item in the comma separated list, see the examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zz}{O{z}mO{h\sb{##1}}}
 {
  #1
  \sp{}\sb
   {
    \cs_set_protected:Nn \__fahim_z_subscript:n { #3 }
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_fahim_z_subscripts_seq { \__fahim_z_subscript:n { ##1 } }
     }
    (\seq_use:Nn \l_fahim_z_subscripts_seq { , })
   }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_fahim_z_subscripts_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\zz{1,2,3}+\zz{4,5,6}=\zz{1,2,3,4,5,6}$

$\zz[Z]{1,2,3}[k_{#1}]$

$\zz{1,2,3}[(#1)]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more complex settings, I suggest a key-value syntax. Here the keys are `var` (for the name of the variable), `outer` to set the overall setting (default is just adding the parentheses) and `inner` for the sequence of actual subscripts. See the given examples. At any moment you can issue `\zzset` to change (in the current scope) one or more of the values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zz}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { fahim/zz } { #1 }
  \fahim_zz:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\zzset}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { fahim/zz } { #1 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { fahim/zz }
 {
  var .tl_set:N = \l__fahim_zz_var_tl,
  outer .code:n = \cs_set_protected:Nn \__fahim_zz_outer:n { #1 },
  inner .code:n = \cs_set_protected:Nn \__fahim_zz_inner:n { #1 },
 }

\seq_new:N \l__fahim_zz_subscripts_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fahim_zz:n
 {
  \tl_use:N \l__fahim_zz_var_tl
  \sp{} % a dummy superscript to lower the subscript
  \sb
   {
    \__fahim_zz_outer:n
     {
      \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
       {
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l__fahim_zz_subscripts_seq { \__fahim_zz_inner:n { ##1 } }
       }
      \seq_use:Nn \l__fahim_zz_subscripts_seq { , }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% initialize
\zzset{
  var=z,
  outer=(#1),
  inner=h_{#1},
}

\begin{document}

$\zz{1,2,3}+\zz{4,5,6}=\zz{1,2,3,4,5,6}$

$\zz[var=Z,inner=k_{#1}]{1,2,3}$

$\zz[outer=i(#1)]{1,2,3}$

$\zz[outer=i(#1),inner=k_{#1}]{1,2,3}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot. :-)

Comment: Is it possible to use this method for formulas such as `z_{i(h_{1},h_{2},h_{3})}` and `z_{k(h_{4},h_{5})}`?

Comment: @FahimB The new version is online.

Answer (score 11):

It's not difficult to extend it to any number of subscripts and without using ExplSyntaxOn:

```
\def\zz#1{\zzA#1,,}
\def\zzA#1,{z_\bgroup(h_{#1}\zzB}
\def\zzB#1,{\ifx\end#1\end)\egroup \else ,h_{#1}\expandafter\zzB\fi}

$\zz{1,2,3}+\zz{4,5,6}=\zz{1,2,3,4,5,6}$

\bye
```

**EDIT** If you need to add an ``index letter'' (i, j like in your comment), then it is possible to do using this code:

```
\def\zz#1#{z_\bgroup#1\zzI}
\def\zzI#1{\zzA#1,,}
\def\zzA#1,{(h_{#1}\zzB}
\def\zzB#1,{\ifx\end#1\end)\egroup \else ,h_{#1}\expandafter\zzB\fi}

$\zz i{1,2,3}+\zz j{4,5,6}=\zz{1,2,3,4,5,6}$

\bye
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this method for formulas such as `z_{i(h_{1},h_{2})}` and `z_{j(h_{3},h_{4},h_{5})}`?

Comment: @FahimB Yes, see above.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will be very thankful if you write the commands for `z_{j_{1}(h_{1},h_{2})}` and `z_{k(h_{3},h_{4},h_{5})}`.

Comment: OK: `\zz j_1{1,2}` and `\zz k{3,4,5}`.

Answer (score 4):

Very easy with the `listofitems` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\zz[1]{
  z_{(
    \setsepchar{,}
    \readlist*\zlist{#1}
    \foreachitem\i\in\zlist{\ifnum\icnt=1\relax\else,\fi h_{\i}}
  )}
}
\begin{document}
$\zz{1,2,3}+\zz{4,5,6}=\zz{1,2,3,4,5,6}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `listofitems` works in plain TeX, as well:

```
\input listofitems.tex
\def\zz#1{
  z_{(
    \setsepchar{,}
    \readlist*\zlist{#1}
    \foreachitem\i\in\zlist{\ifnum\icnt=1\relax\else,\fi h_{\i}}
  )}
}
$\zz{1,2,3}+\zz{4,5,6}=\zz{1,2,3,4,5,6}$
\end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use e-TeX. (It seems rather simple to me.) Assuming that you have three subsequent indices every time you would say

```
\newcommand*\zz[1]{%
  \@tempcnta\numexpr#1+1\relax
  \@tempcntb\numexpr#1+2\relax
  z_{(%
    h_{#1}+h_{\the\@tempcnta}+h_{\the\@tempcntb}%
  )}
}
```

and then call `\zz{1}` resp. `\zz{4}`.

[image: output_solution1]

To add in a few generalisations, i.e. arbitrary number of indices and specified indices is not a big deal:

```
\newcommand*\zzz[2][h]{%
  \def\forplus{\def\forplus{+}}
  z_{(%
    \@for\i:=#2\do{\forplus#1_{\i}}%
  )}
}
```

Note the optional parameter for the subscripts of first order:

```
\begin{gather*}
  \zzz{1,2,3}\\
  \zzz{4,5,6}\\
  \zzz[p]{7,11,13,17}
\end{gather*}
```

[image: output_solution2]

If you want to you can get really sophisticated by declaring something that acts like

```
\indexloop[<delimiter>][<format>]{<indices>}
```

where `<format>:='<superscript>_<opt. delimiter><subscript><opt. delimiter>'`

defined by

```
\makeatletter
\def\defaultsup{z}
\def\defaultsub{h}
\def\defaultdll{(}
\def\defaultdlr{)}
\def\defaultsep{+}
\def\indexloop{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar[
    {\indexl@op}
    {\indexl@op[\defaultsup_\defaultdll\defaultsub\defaultdlr]}
}
\def\indexl@op[#1]{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar[
    {\indexl@@p[{#1}]}
    {\indexl@@p[\defaultsep][{#1}]}
}
\def\indexl@@p[#1][#2]#3{%
  \def\forsep{\def\forsep{#1}}
  \def\customsup{}
  \def\customsub{}
  \def\customdll{}
  \def\customdlr{}
  \process@format#2\@end
  \customsup_{%
    \customdll
    \@for\i:=#3\do{\forsep\customsub_{\i}}%
    \customdlr
  }%
}
\def\process@format#1_#2\@end{%
\def\customsup{#1}
\process@sub#2\@@end
}
\def\process@sub#1{
\ifx#1\@@end\else
  \ifcat#1x
    \edef\customsub{\customsub#1}
  \else
    \ifx\customdll\@empty
      \def\customdll{#1}
    \else
      \ifx\customdlr\@empty
        \def\customdlr{#1}
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \expandafter\process@sub
\fi
}
\makeatother
```

Here is a short test of the last solution.

```
\begin{gather*}
  \indexloop{1,2,3}\\
  \indexloop{4,5,6}\\
  \indexloop[z_(p)]{7,11,13,17}\\
  \indexloop[-][z_\langle x\rangle]{8,9,10,12,14,15,16}\\
  \indexloop[,][{a_[i]}]{1,2}
\end{gather*}
```

[image: output_solution3]

### Complete Code

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\zz[1]{%
  \@tempcnta\numexpr#1+1\relax
  \@tempcntb\numexpr#1+2\relax
  z_{(%
    h_{#1}+h_{\the\@tempcnta}+h_{\the\@tempcntb}%
  )}
}
\newcommand*\zzz[2][h]{%
  \def\forplus{\def\forplus{+}}
  z_{(%
    \@for\i:=#2\do{\forplus#1_{\i}}%
  )}
}
\def\defaultsup{z}
\def\defaultsub{h}
\def\defaultdll{(}
\def\defaultdlr{)}
\def\defaultsep{+}
\def\indexloop{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar[
    {\indexl@op}
    {\indexl@op[\defaultsup_\defaultdll\defaultsub\defaultdlr]}
}
\def\indexl@op[#1]{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar[
    {\indexl@@p[{#1}]}
    {\indexl@@p[\defaultsep][{#1}]}
}
\def\indexl@@p[#1][#2]#3{%
  \def\forsep{\def\forsep{#1}}
  \def\customsup{}
  \def\customsub{}
  \def\customdll{}
  \def\customdlr{}
  \process@format#2\@end
  \customsup_{%
    \customdll
    \@for\i:=#3\do{\forsep\customsub_{\i}}%
    \customdlr
  }%
}
\def\process@format#1_#2\@end{%
\def\customsup{#1}
\process@sub#2\@@end
}
\def\process@sub#1{
\ifx#1\@@end\else
  \ifcat#1x
    \edef\customsub{\customsub#1}
  \else
    \ifx\customdll\@empty
      \def\customdll{#1}
    \else
      \ifx\customdlr\@empty
        \def\customdlr{#1}
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \expandafter\process@sub
\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \zz{1}\\
  \zz{4}
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*}
  \zzz{1,2,3}\\
  \zzz{4,5,6}\\
  \zzz[p]{7,11,13,17}
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*}
  \indexloop{1,2,3}\\
  \indexloop{4,5,6}\\
  \indexloop[z_(p)]{7,11,13,17}\\
  \indexloop[-][z_\langle x\rangle]{8,9,10,12,14,15,16}\\
  \indexloop[,][{a_[i]}]{1,2}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

### Edit

Even the first solution can be more sophisticated by implementing the step length:

```
\newcommand*\zz[2][1]{%
  \@tempcnta\numexpr#2+1*#1\relax
  \@tempcntb\numexpr#2+2*#1\relax
  z_{(%
    h_{#2}+h_{\the\@tempcnta}+h_{\the\@tempcntb}%
  )}
}
```

`\[\zz[2]{0}\]` would then compile to `z_{h_0+h_2+h_4}` as expected.